# How to get the Broker's UUID, hostname, from an ESQL code running on an IBM IIB 10+?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

How can we get the Broker's UUID, hostname, from an ESQL code running on an IBM IIB, version 10+?

(I could get the BrokerName from:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak09512_.htm

but I don't seem to see anyway to access a Broker's UUID, hostname from an ESQL code running on an IBM IIB engine.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So when it comes to ESQL you can't get it. Which has irritated me for years, I mean why hide it.

**If you are allowed to use Java Nodes** then you can get it by calling the getUUID method of BrokerProxy.

```
BrokerProxy b = BrokerProxy.getLocalInstance("MYBROKER");
String b_uuid = b.getUUID();
```

**If not then you can**:

- Use mqsireportbroker  to find out the UUID
- Use the Webadmin console to add a UserDefined Configurable Service definition. Let's call it BrokerUUID with a property of UUID and the value you got from mqsireportbroker. They hide inside the Operational Policy section
- Call the IBM Integration RESTful API /apiv1/policy/configurableservices/UserDefined/BrokerUUID using an HTTPRequest or RESTRequest node.
- The RESTful API is currently found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.restapi.doc/path__policy_configurableservices_-configurableServiceType-_-configurableServicename-.html or by searching for IBM Integration RESTful API
- This is viable as a Nodes UUID doesn't change unless you delete and recreate it.

**If you have scripted deploys** then:

- Add a mqsireportbroker  command to it and scrape the UUID value
- In the flow that needs the UUID value add a UDP(User Defined Property) UDP_BrokerUUID to it and set it to something like UNKNOWN
- Then in your deploy script use mqsiapplybaroverride to change it to the scraped value.

**Then there is IBM Integration API Exerciser** which will show you how the API's work.
install_dir\server\sample\IntegrationAPI\StartIntegrationAPIExerciser

Finally out of curiosity why do you need the Node UUID?

**Caching**

Goes something like this. Create a jar file similar to the one in @Daniels link. Note

```
DECLARE S_CacheRow SHARED ROW; -- Done at global level
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE DoingSomething
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    CACHE: BEGIN ATOMIC
        IF NOT EXISTS(S_CacheRow.UUID[]) THEN
            SET S_CacheRow.BrokerUUID = GetBrokerUUID();
        END IF;
        SET Environment.BrokerUUID = S_CacheRow.BrokerUUID;
    END CACHE;
END;
END MODULE;

CREATE FUNCTION GetBrokerUUID() 
RETURNS CHAR 
LANGUAGE JAVA 
EXTERNAL NAME "mycompany.common.GetBrokerInfo.getBrokerUUID" 
;

import com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.*;

public class GetBrokerInfo {

    public static String getBrokerUUID() {

    BrokerProxy bp = null;
    try {
        bp = BrokerProxy.getInstance();   
    } catch (ConfigManagerProxyException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error connecting: " + ex);
    }

    String brokerUUID = '';
    if (bp != null) {
        brokerUUID = bp.getUUID();
        bp.disconnect();
    }  
    return brokerUUID;    
}
```

Please note I wrote this freehand and it's untested. But it does cover the salient points. You'll need to compile to a jar and put the jar in the shared classes folder typically /var/mqsi/shared-classes

Comment: Thanks for the info. When doing the ad-hoc logging in esql codes, we'd like to add the Broker UUID so we could have more complete info on the context where/when Exceptions occur for audit/monitoring purposes. (And we have a lot of esql codes).

Comment: Be careful when using `BrokerProxy`; you need to call `disconnect()` after usage otherwise you will get an OutOfMemory eventually; or you cache it, see http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=376592

Comment: Hello @NamNguyen I added another option.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Accessible Properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak04897_.htm) page, the broker UUID and hostname is not available.

But you can get the broker UUID with a [Monitoring Event](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac60386_.htm); here a sample from the InfoCenter:

```xml
<wmb:messageFlowData>
   <wmb:broker wmb:UUID="d53122ae-1c01-0000-0080-b1b02528c6bf"
            wmb:name="myNode"/>
   <wmb:executionGroup wmb:UUID="d43122ae-1c01-0000-0080-b1b02528c6bf"
            wmb:name="default"/>
   <wmb:messageFlow wmb:UUID="e6d224ae-1c01-0000-0080-9100cd1a61f7"
            wmb:name="myMessageFlow" wmb:threadId="4201"
            wmb:uniqueFlowName="myNode.default.myApplication.myMessageFlow"/>
   <wmb:node wmb:nodeLabel="MQInput1" wmb:nodeType="ComIbmMqInputNode"
            wmb:terminal="in" wmb:detail="MYMESSAGEFLOW.IN"/>
</wmb:messageFlowData>
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, but it's it's ad-hoc logging in esql codes that we'd like to get it.